# Function with two stages to define parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I need to define functions that get called in two stages.
The first stage only sets a subset of parameters and the second stage runs the function with some additional parameters.

*I didn't know how to name the title to this question.*

Currently I'm doing this by defining three functions.
The first function returns a new function that has the parameters set.
After that, calling the returned function will actually call the final function.

The current solution looks like this:

```
def my_function(stage1_param1, stage1_param2):
    return lambda stage2_param1, stage2_param2: my_function_op(stage1_param1, stage1_param2, stage2_param1, stage2_param2)

def my_function_op(stage1_param1, stage1_param2, stage2_param1, stage2_param2):
    # do stuff
```

I would like to reduce boilerplate here and have a more compact version.

Is there a better / shorter solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just looking for partial function application; your `my_function` is in some sense a specialized implementation of `functools.partial`.

```
from functools import partial


def my_function_op(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    # do stuff


f = partial(my_function_op, a1, a2)

x = f(a3, a4)  # x = my_function_op(a1, a2, a3, a4)
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

You can just define a function within a function:

```
def my_function(stage1_param1, stage1_param2):
    def stage2(stage2_param1, stage2_param2):
        ...  # do stuff
    return stage2
```

You can then use `my_function` like this:

```
>>> f = my_function("foo", "bar")
>>> f("ham", "spam")
```

Inside the inner function, all the arguments are bound to the correct values.

This can be nested as far as needed, just remember to return the defined functions.

Comment: Replacing the `lambda` expression with a `def` statement isn't a significant change to what the OP already has.

Comment: I disagree, using a proper function allows the use of statements, not just expressions, and therefore avoids the use of a secondary function that has to be called from the lambda expression. The full logic of the function can be expressed inside the nested definition.